# Linking problem when trying to cross-compile a qt application using cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm currently switching the build system of my Qt application from qmake to cmake. While trying to cross-compile for Windows with MinGW (static Qt build), I came across a strange problem I cannot explain:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(noble)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options thread REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtCore QtGui)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
find_package(Armadillo)
find_package(Qwt6 REQUIRED)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

include(${QT_USE_FILE})

set(LIBRARIES
    ${Qwt6_Qt4_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
    ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
    )

set(DEFINITIONS
    ${QT_DEFINITIONS}
    ${BLAS_LINKER_FLAGS}
    ${LAPACK_LINKER_FLAGS}
    -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
    )

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(plugins)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(noble_SOURCES
    #file names...
    )

set(noble_HEADERS
    #file names...
    )

set(noble_FORMS
    #file names...
    )

QT4_WRAP_UI(noble_FORMS_HEADERS ${noble_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(noble_HEADERS_MOC ${noble_HEADERS})

include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qwt6_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

add_definitions(${DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(noble
    ${noble_SOURCES}
    ${noble_HEADERS_MOC}
    ${noble_FORMS_HEADERS}
    )

target_link_libraries(noble 
    ${LIBRARIES}
    -lQtGui -lQtCore
    -ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lmng -lz -limm32 -llcms -lwinmm
    -fopenmp
    )
```

I am now trying to get rid of the manually set compiler flags right in the end. If I omit the `-lQtGui -lQtCore` I get a whole bunch of undefined references like

```
/home/mjung/Programme/mingw-cross-env-2.21/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.0/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/lib/libQtGui.a(qapplication.o):qapplication.cpp:(.text+0x2340): undefined reference to `QBasicTimer::stop()'
```

If i keep these flags, the program compiles fine.

The strange thing now is the following:

cmake's g++ call **with** `-lQtGui -lQtCore` flags:

```
/home/mjung/Programme/mingw-cross-env-2.21/usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-g++
-Wl,--whole-archive
CMakeFiles/noble.dir/objects.a
-Wl,--no-whole-archive
-o ../noble.exe
-Wl,--out-implib,../libnoble.dll.a
-Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libqwt.a
-Wl,-Bstatic
-lQtCore -lQtGui
-lboost_program_options-mt
-lboost_thread-mt
-Wl,-Bdynamic
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libblas.a
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/liblapack.a
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libblas.a
-lQtGui -lQtCore
-ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lmng -lz -limm32 -llcms -lwinmm
-fopenmp
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/liblapack.a
-lQtGui -lQtCore
-ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lmng -lz -limm32 -llcms -lwinmm
-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

cmake's g++ call **without** `-lQtGui -lQtCore` flags:

```
/home/mjung/Programme/mingw-cross-env-2.21/usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-g++
-Wl,--whole-archive
CMakeFiles/noble.dir/objects.a
-Wl,--no-whole-archive
-o ../noble.exe
-Wl,--out-implib,../libnoble.dll.a
-Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libqwt.a
-Wl,-Bstatic
-lQtCore -lQtGui
-lboost_program_options-mt
-lboost_thread-mt
-Wl,-Bdynamic
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libblas.a
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/liblapack.a
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/libblas.a

-ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lmng -lz -limm32 -llcms -lwinmm
-fopenmp
/home/mjung/Programme/windows_builds/usr/lib/liblapack.a

-ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lmng -lz -limm32 -llcms -lwinmm
-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Even if I do **not** set the compiler flags manually the `FindQt4.cmake` script still sets them. But this doesn't seem to be enough. I absolutely don't understand why it makes a difference if the flags are set once automatically, or three times, if I add them manually. Does this have something to do with the order of the flags?

Do you have any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

Nevermind...

I just changed the order of the libraries from

```
set(LIBRARIES
    ${Qwt6_Qt4_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
    ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

to

```
set(LIBRARIES
    ${Qwt6_Qt4_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
    ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

I do not quite understand why it has to be this way round, but now it works...

PS: I would have posted this as an answer, but I am not allowed to do so yet, due to lack of reputation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is

Comment: changing the order or libraries works, probably means that  `QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY` depends on `QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many architectures do a single pass through the library list when linking. i.e. If you have an undefined symbol, a library that's later in the link list must define it. The linker won't search 'backwards' through the library list to resolve the symbol.

In this case, QtGui has a dependency on QtCore. QtCore therefore must appear after QtGui in the link list.

The easiest way around this is to use the ${QT_LIBRARIES} cmake variable that gets magically defined when you do the FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4...). It has all the relevant Qt libs in the right order for the link.

[FindQt4 CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aFindQt4)